# Mac network ping source code compile error

Tags: c, xcode, macos, ping, icmp

I download the Mac OS network ping source code from Apple: http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/network_cmds/network_cmds-356.8.tar.gz

and compile it in xcode, but get errors in both 10.7 and 10.6,

> 'IP_NO_IFT_CELLULAR' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   'SO_TRAFFIC_CLASS' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   'SO_RECV_TRAFFIC_CLASS' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   'SO_TRAFFIC_CLASS' undeclared (first use in this function)

Did I miss something?

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using? (If I open the project in XCode 4.2.1, I get errors as well, but those are different from yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was possible that you needed to import a networking framework into your project, but Apple doesn't provide any description or information about the project you've downloaded.

For posterity's sake:
To add frameworks, select the project in the top left, then click your target, pick 'Build Phases' from the top of the resulting page, 'Link Binary With Libraries', '+'.

I finally managed to get it to build after exhaustive googling by adding the following to the ping.c file (the one flagged with the errors):

```
#define IP_NO_IFT_CELLULAR  6969 /* for internal use only */
#define IP_NO_IFT_PDP       IP_NO_IFT_CELLULAR /* deprecated */
#define SO_TRAFFIC_CLASS        0x1086      /* Traffic class (int)*/
#define SO_RECV_TRAFFIC_CLASS   0x1087      /* Receive traffic class (bool)*/
```

Which amusingly came from other open source Apple projects that Google had indexed.

Comment: Nothing of information from Apple Open Source site, no idea which framework should be add to project.

Comment: Try those new defines I've edited my answer to include, I got it to build with them.