# Check internet connection or check internet connection constantly

Tags: c++, c, xcode

How can i check internet connection in c++ or c, i'm using mac & cant find a good way. If

possible i want to check internet connection constantly' so i can save the users data.

Please provide me with examples, information and ideas.

THanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "check internet connection constant"?

Comment: This can be mybe done in loop, but how to check internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

Call system("ping www.google.com").

If the process dies or becomes slow, then your internet connection is doing badly.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but how can i get the return of the result? should i use pipe ...or? any example please..

Comment: If you're in C++ you should be able to connect to the stdout of the process, which will return a line of text every time a ping succeeds.

Comment: There was some statistic that google is used by majority of people to check whether internet connection is up or not rather than actual search :)

Comment: Note that many schools and businesses block ping packets.  Also, if google goes out of business or renames itself, this may fail in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing a lightweight ICMP to ping a remote host periodically.

Maybe this question can shed some light: [Mac network ping source code compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776527/mac-network-ping-source-code-compile-error)